# How to make thread groups user share single Foreach control?

Tags: jmeter, performance

How to make thread group users share single Foreach control, for ex. I have 10 user and one foreach controller for 10K (JDBC request) records, I want to process this 10K records by 10 users(Thread group user) so that each user process 1k records. Presently for my setup with Thread group with 10 user and 1 JDBC request and Foreach controll the total requests are 10 * 10K = 100k which is 10 time repeated.
 Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be writing the variables into a file like:

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) under the ForEach Controller and use the following condition:

   ```
   ${__threadNum} == 1
   ```
2. Add [Test Action Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) as a child of the If Controller. It will act as a "container" and won't generate any extra sample results in your report
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the Test Action sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File('test.csv') << vars.get('foo') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   ```

   Replace `foo` with what you have as "Output variable name" in the ForEach Controller
4. Add JDBC Request sampler under the ForEach Controller (the same level)
5. Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) as a child of the JDBC Request sampler and configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

   Again, replace `foo` with the expected variable name (the same as "Output variable name" in the ForEach Controller")

Comment: Dmitri Thanks, It is allowing Thread number 1 only to run with this condition ${__threadNum} == 1, whereas what I am trying is all thread divide the count and run (some what like multi tasking).

Comment: what is the use of this "new File('test.csv') << vars.get('foo') << System.getProperty('line.separator') " even I disable this it is working with no difference